# How to write sql query if result value is null and then try with another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having difficulty to write a query where for my first query if i get a null or no result then i need to run a second query, below are my two sql queries, in either of the query one query return null and one will return values.

sql query-1:

```
select b.* 
from  idm.relationships a, idm.persons b 
where a.fullobject like ${orgId}
  and substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(a.fullobject,'\"firstId\":\"',-1),'\"',1),'/',-1) = b.objectId 
order by b.LoginId asc;
```

sql query-2:

```
select b.*
from  idm.relationships a, idm.persons b 
where a.fullobject like ${orgId}
  and substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(a.fullobject,'\"secondId\":\"',-1),'\"',1),'/',-1) = b.objectId
order by b.LoginId asc;
```

I am trying to understand how i can combine above both queries into one query with IF ELSE condition when one gives null and other gives result with some values.

Comment: Use `UNION` to combine both queries, then remove rows with NULL values. Notice that UNION will select only distinct values.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? If it's 5.7 or later you should use the built-in JSON functions

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "or operator" to filter appropriate condition:

```
select b.* from idm.relationships a, idm.persons b where a.fullobject like ${orgId} and (substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(a.fullobject,'\"firstId\":\"',-1),'\"',1),'/',-1) = b.objectId or substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(a.fullobject,'\"secondId\":\"',-1),'\"',1),'/',-1) = b.objectId) order by b.LoginId asc;
```